# The right way to implement multiple selects from database data (list menu or radio button?)

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am making a website that will show night club revelers events and night establishments in a big city. Events could number in the hundreds.

A user should be able to add certain details when adding their event on the site e.g.(in the events table) `event_name, event_description, event_date, event_photo_url etc.`

I want users to be able to search or find certain events or establishments based on interests or music genre. 
I have an interest table and a genre table in MySQL:

### interests table

```
interest_id  interest-name  
1            Shoot Pool  
2            Karaoke 
3            Lounge 
4            Live Band
5            Dance
6            Watch Sports
```

### genre table

```
genre_id  genre_name   
1         Hip Hop 
2         Soul 
3         Reggae 
4         Pop 
5         Bangra  
6         Rock 
7         House 
8         Country 
9         Gospel 
10        Carribean 
11        Bongo 
12        Genge 
13        Mugithi 
14        Dholuo 
15        Kamba 
16        Classical 
17        Childrens 
18        Latin 
19        Jazz 
20        Musicals 
21        Middle Eastern
```

I have 2 other tables to link events with genres and events with interests ie;

event_genre table

```
  event_genre_id              
  event_id               
  genre_id
```

and event_interest table

```
  event_interest_id            
  event_id               
  interest_id
```

An establishment or event can have more than one interest e.g a club where one can play pool and watch the game. The same goes with music genres. A wide variety of music can be played in an establishment or event. 
A user whould be able to make multiple selects from genres and interests.
My question is, do I have drop down list menus for each of the interests and genres? Can I have multiple selects for a drop down list menu and/or radio buttons? Is there a better way of implementing what I need?

Comment: Are you asking about how to represent this in the UI, or how to implement it when calling the database?

Comment: @pkaeding. I am asking for both. I have never used a list menu where a user could select more than one item.

Comment: In that case, I agree with @Aaron's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with a mess of checkboxes. The user would be able to check all of the interests or whatever that they are interested in. To process this you would just build a list of checked values and then pass that list into the query to filter the results. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is one way, however, is there a way I can be able to bring up the interests or genres dynamically as I have been able to do in the past with dynamic select lists with info from a database?

Comment: Certainly! Just query the tables (genre, for example) for all entries in there. Then foreach of the entries you can output a corresponding checkbox on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could do two list boxes.  This would allow you to select multiple genres and multiple interests in two simple controls which would save realestate and allow you to easily display and sort the available selections...

then on your server side you would just have to parse the values to build your query... THAT will probably be the hard part.

your value will more likely be returned as an array... not sure how that all works in php, but you would split your items down to an array object and basically loop through them.

you would then add AND genre = arItem(x) to your query and the same with interests.

Comment: I think multi-select list boxes would save a lot of space, especially with the number of genres and interests you have.

Comment: yeah I work on a project with a set of list boxes that contains 30+ items at any given point in time based on the underlying data.  check boxes can get messy.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I can be able to dynamically generate the list items from the DB using list boxes. I however do not have any clue how to parse the values to build my query. I'll have to research on that

Comment: good luck.  it sounds like your queries could end up being very complex.  if your user has a specific interest and a large number of genres it could get messy.